# integrate rollbar to my Cakephp project

Tags: cakephp, rollbar

i wan't to integrate Rollbar to my cakephp project but i dont know where to include the code referencing to rolbar in my app ? 
i have use this code

```
<?php
use \Rollbar\Rollbar;

// Installs global error and exception handlers
$config = array(
    // required
    'access_token' => 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    // optional - environment name
    'environment' => 'production',
);
Rollbar::init($config);
```

But it works only for the page that i have added to, so please help how can i configure rollbar for cakephp application.

Comment: Hey Wajdi - The best way to get help w/ rollbar-php is to create an issue at https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-php/issues.  Our engineers respond directly to those tickets and can help you out.

Comment: @JesseGibbs Thanks , problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should put this code in **bootstrap.php**

```
use \Rollbar\Rollbar;

// Installs global error and exception handlers
$config = array(
    // required
    'access_token' => 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    // optional - environment name
    'environment' => 'production',
    // optional - path to directory your code is in. Used for linking stack traces.
    'root' => '/Users/brian/www/myapp'
);
Rollbar::init($config);
```